# how to setup lotus notes database to allow more than one concurrent user?

Tags: lotus-domino, domino-designer-eclipse

Morning all,

I've recently started making an application for Lotus Notes 8.5.3 using Domino Designer 8.5.3. but the issue I am having is that only one user in my network can access the view at the same time. I have added all relevant users to my Acesss Control List. The database is accessed locally through Lotus Notes, not through web. I have my .nsf file in a folder that all users have access to. When the database is opened on my computer, other users who try to access the same .nsf file get the following message, and vice versa:

*"This database is currently in use by another person or process, and cannot be accessed at this time. In order to share a Notes database, it must be accessed via a Domino Server by all users of the database."*

The question is, how do I make my database accessible to more than one user at a time? The database only allows users to browse through documents and nothing more.
I have not used any template, I have built the database from scratch.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to place your database on an **IBM Notes Domino server**. Users have to access your database on this server, not just from a file server.

Comment: ahem, the *server* is called Domino, Notes being the favorite, but far from only, client to access it.

That being sait, it's pretty common to call it a Notes server.